# Want to save webview data from android to sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, webview

I have tried to use javascriptInterface to parse data from webview to text view so that i can store the text in sqlite but didn't get success. I am a newbie to android So please guide me how can i achieve that

Comment: There might be someone here who can help you fix your code if you include it. But I doubt you find too many volunteers to *write everything* for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
final Context myctxt = this; //your activity or application context
    class MyJavaScriptInterface
    {

        @JavascriptInterface
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public void processHTML(String html)
        {
            // process the html as needed by the app
            DBHelpher dbhelpher=new DBHelpher(myctxt);
            dbhelpher.insertHtmlString(html);

        }
    }

    final WebView browser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.browser);
    /* JavaScript must be enabled if you want it to work, obviously */
    browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    /* Register a new JavaScript interface called HTMLOUT */
    browser.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "HTMLOUT");

    /* WebViewClient must be set BEFORE calling loadUrl! */
    browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
        {
            /* This call inject JavaScript into the page which just finished loading. */
            browser.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.processHTML('<head>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</head>');");
        }
    });

    /* load a web page */
    browser.loadUrl("YOUR LINK");


    Create class for sqlite

    public class DBHelpher extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
    {

     Context context;
        public final String TABLE_SAMPLE="test";
          public final String COLUMN_ID="id";
        public final String COLUMN_HTMLSTRING="htmlstring";

        public final String CREATE_TABLE__SAMPLE_SQL="create table " + TABLE_SAMPLE
                + " (" + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
                + COLUMN_HTMLSTRING + " text "
                + ");";


        public DBHelpher(Context context)
        {
            super(context, "DATABASENAME.db", null, 1);
            this.context=context;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE__SAMPLE_SQL);


        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        }


        public void insertHtmlString(String htmlString)
        {

            SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(COLUMN_HTMLSTRING,htmlString);
             database.insert(TABLE_SAMPLE, null, values);


        }


    }
```

You will get the whole Html contnet in processHTML method. and it wont make another request for webpage.